# Why are component `refs` `undefined` when I try to access them?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I am using `React v0.13.3` and `JSXTransformer v0.13.3` to create a couple of simple components, each of which renders an input field along with a button inside a paragraph. When any button is clicked, I want to show the associated input value using an alert. I am trying to use `refs` to get the value, but for some reason it is not working, and shows `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    show: function() {
        alert(this.refs.test.value);
    },
    render: function() {
        return(<p><input type="text" ref="test" /><button type="button" onClick={this.show}>Show</button></p>);
    }
});
React.render(<div><CommentBox /><CommentBox /></div>, document.getElementById('commentbox'));
```

Comment: That react version is a bit old.  You might try updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working just fine! I put it in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/superKalo/oqre0zfx/).

However, **that's not a good approach for your specific use-case**. In general, you must try **not to overuse `refs`**. Here's a quote from the [ReactJS related docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs):

> Your first inclination may be to use refs to "make things happen" in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy.

So, here is a better approach:

For similar purposes, just like the one you need, using a [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) is the preferred way. I suggest you to consider using your [Component `state`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state).

Therefore, here's an example how you can achieve the same result, using the Component `state`. I am using your code snippet as a base:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            // That's the default input value
            value: ''
        };
    },
    show: function() {
        alert(this.state.value);
    },
    handleChange: function(event) {
        // Each time the input's value is changed, the state gets an update
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <p>
                <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.show}>Show</button>
            </p>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <div><CommentBox /><CommentBox /></div>,
    document.getElementById('commentbox')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to bind `onChange` of the input to set the value on the state, like so:

```
<input onChange={event => this.setState({value: event.target.value})} />
```

Now `this.state.value` always has the current value of the field. Then on the show function, just do:

```
show: function() {
    alert(this.state.value);
}
```